# TypeScript safely typed property with dynamic name

Tags: typescript

Not sure if this is possible but I'd like to write a function where I take in a string and an object.

The type of the second object should contain a property with a name that is the same as the before mentioned string and have a certain type.

E.g.

```
// No error
someFuncion("foo", {foo: 42})

// Error
someFuncion("foo", {foo: "a string instead of a number"})
someFuncion("foo", {bar: 42})
```

Can anyone show me what the type signature for this function would be please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a generic function with a default generic type.

```
function someFunction<T extends string>(param1: T, param2: Record<T, number>) {}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EMAnGMAcwD4AKABwEMKWBbARgC5FsANIlbsOAJj4AlFBDgViOIWBAcARigp0AlIgDeAXwBQh1BgYAiU1HNDdiS+mt8ADPq0BuRAHoviAO5yANZoJo4WVjZ69hF8DhjmiG7evsRw6GAA5FD+QaFmcdYCdgXmLkLmaMTApYjOYm6ePoip6Vk5FIGGQA)

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, can you explain the `string = string` bit? I come from a C# background so restricting a generic param to a certain type makes sense so I understand `T extends string` but it's the following equals that throws me a bit.

Comment: i just realized that it is not at all necessary in this function type. 
its basically a default value if no type is provided. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that very easily using [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

The function must accept a string and an object.

Using Typescript interfaces (suggested):

The parameters of obj must follow the interface IObject.

```js
interface IObject {
  foo: number;
};

function someFunction(str: string, obj: IObject): void {
  // ...
}
```

Without interface declaration "inline":

```js
function someFunction(str: string, obj: { foo: number }): void {
  // ...
}
```

Now if you try to run the examples you will get:

1. `someFuncion("foo", {foo: 42})` -> *NO ERROR*
2. `someFuncion("foo", {foo: "a string instead of a number"})` -> *Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.*
3. `someFuncion("foo", {bar: 42})` -> *Argument of type '{ bar: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: number; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type '{ foo: number; }.*

Comment: I need the property name "foo" to be dynamic/flexible, unfortunately this solution only works with "foo". Thanks for spending the time to answer though.